# Sympy solve raises an error that one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, sympy

As title say, sympy solve returns an error I don't know how to resolve.

My code

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
import numpy as np
z = 10
h = 0.1
r = 10
He = 10

aa = 1+(h*r)
bb = -1
mm = np.zeros([He,He])
m = np.zeros([He+1])

for i in range(He):
    mm[i,i] = aa
    if i is 0:
        m[i] = -bb * z
    if i > 0:
        mm[i,i-1] = bb

ln = solve(mm,m)
```

I get an error :

```
  The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Which line gives you this error?

Comment: What do you mean which page?

Comment: shouldn't `sympy.solvers.solve` be used with `sympy.Symbol` ? You don't have any symbol in your code. *EDIT* : `mm` and `m` don't have coherent shapes, what is the equation you want to solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't really clear without an explanation of what it should be doing, I see 2 problems:

First `sympy` is a library for symbolic math with infinite precision. It uses its own `Symbol` to define variables and `sympy.solvers.solve` asks for an equation and a list of symbols (the equation should depend on these symbols). See the doc for this : [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html)

The other point is `mm` has a shape of `(10, 10)` and `m` is a vector of length `11`. What equation do you want to solve ?

My solution to your problem is IF you want to solve an equation like `mm @ X = m` then use `np.linalg.solve(mm, m)` but you need to have correct shapes for this.

Comment: THank you that saved it! And yes you were right I shouldn't have m = np.zeros([He+1]) it should be m = np.zeros([He]). I was trying to solve euler backward equation in implicit way.